# How to pass data from Datagridview1 to Datagridview2 in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I had this problem on how to pass data from a specific row in datagridview1 to datagridview2.

For example;

This is my data in datagridview1

```
 Code     ProductID    Description           Price
 C1        0001        Office Furnitures     10,000.00
 C2        0002        Steel Cabinets        10,000.00
 C3        0003        Swivle Chair           3,500.00
```

Pass data to Datagridview2

```
 Product Description           Price
 Office Furnitures          10,000.00
 Steel Cabinets             10,000.00
 Swivle Chair                3,500.00
```

I want to pass some data of specific columns in Datagridview1 to Datagridview2

Please, i need your help on this. Thanks

Comment: How would you move something from one bag to another? You'd take it out of the first bag and then put it in the other. Taking something out of a bag is the same regardless of what you intend to do with it and putting something into a bag is the same regardless of where it came from.  This is the same. You get the data from the first grid in exactly the same way you get data from a grid on any other occasion.  You then put that data into the second grid in exactly the same way as on any other occasion. There is no magic.

Comment: I am new to vb.net bro, so can you share me some code please on how to do it.. thanks

Comment: Nope.  Getting data into and out of a `DataGridView` is pretty basic stuff and you can learn how to do it easily with a bit of research.  We're not here to teach you the basics.  Do your research, make an honest attempt and if it doesn't work then post back and show us exactly what you've done and explain exactly how it doesn't meet your expectations. That means posting the relevant code and any error messages that are generated.  If you have no code to post then a question on SO is premature.

Comment: Yah right..thanks bro..

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple answer to my problem. Thanks to you @jmcilhinney..

This is the code:

```
Dim n As Integer = 0
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvSTSub.Rows
        If dgvSTSub.Rows.Count <> n + 1 Then
            StudentTransaction.dgvReceipt.Rows.Add()
            StudentTransaction.dgvReceipt.Rows(n).Cells(0).Value = r.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
            StudentTransaction.dgvReceipt.Rows(n).Cells(1).Value = r.Cells(0).Value
        End If
        n += 1
    Next
```

But i got another problem with my data. How about if some items in my datagridview1 that are negative. It should return only the positive values into datagridview2. How will i do it? @jmcilhinney